# Calculating the cumulative sum with some conditions (gaps-and-islands problem)

Tags: sql, window-functions, cumulative-sum, gaps-and-islands, dbt

Sorry if the title is a bit vague please suggest a title if you think it can articulate the problem. I'll start with what data I have and the end result I'm trying to get and then the TLDR:

**This is the table I have:**

Each row is a transaction. Outgoing amounts are negative, incomings are positive. The transactions can either be someone spending money ('spend' event) or it can be a loan disbursement into their account (amount > 0 and event = 'loan') or it can be them paying back their loan (amount < 0 and event = 'loan').

| row number | id | created | amount | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | -200 | spend |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1000 | loan |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-01-03 | -200 | spend |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-01-04 | -500 | spend |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-01-05 | -500 | loan |
| 6 | 1 | 2022-01-06 | 100 | spend |
| 7 | 1 | 2022-01-07 | -500 | spend |
| 8 | 1 | 2022-01-08 | 1000 | loan |
| 9 | 1 | 2022-01-09 | -100 | spend |

**I'm trying to make:**

| row number | id | created | amount | event | cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | -200 | spend | -200 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1000 | loan | 1000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-01-03 | -200 | spend | 800 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-01-04 | -500 | spend | 300 |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-01-05 | -500 | loan | 300 |
| 6 | 1 | 2022-01-06 | 100 | spend | 300 |
| 7 | 1 | 2022-01-07 | -500 | spend | -200 |
| 8 | 1 | 2022-01-08 | 1000 | loan | 1000 |
| 9 | 1 | 2022-01-09 | -100 | spend | 900 |

**Required logic:**

I want to get a special cumulative sum which sums the amount only when:
`(the amount is < 0 AND the event is spend) OR (when amount is > 0 AND event is loan)`
.

The thing is I want the cumulative sum to start when that first positive loan amount. I don't care about anything before the positive loan amount and if they are counted it will obscure the results. The requirement is trying to select the rows which the loan enabled (if the loan is 1000 then we want to select the rows that add up to -1000 but only when event is spend and amount < 0).

**my attempt**

```
WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2021-01-01' AS created,
  -200 AS amount,
  'spend' AS scheme

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2022-01-02' AS created,
  1000 AS amount,
  'loan' AS scheme

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2022-01-03' AS created,
  -200 AS amount,
  'spend' AS scheme
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2022-01-04' AS created,
  -500 AS amount,
  'spend' AS scheme
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2022-01-05' AS created,
  -500 AS amount,
  'loan' AS scheme
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2022-01-06' AS created,
  100 AS amount,
  'spend' AS scheme

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2022-01-07' AS created,
  -500 AS amount,
  'spend' AS scheme

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2022-01-08' AS created,
  1000 AS amount,
  'loan' AS scheme

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  1 AS id, 
  '2022-01-09' AS created,
  -100 AS amount,
  'spend' AS scheme

)

SELECT 
*,
SUM(CASE WHEN (scheme != 'loan' AND amount<0) OR (scheme = 'loan' AND amount > 0) THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created ASC) AS cumulative_sum_spend
 FROM tmp
```

**Question**

How do I make the cumulative sum reset at row 2 (not conditional to the row number - the requirement is the positive loan amount)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a gaps-and-islands problem if I am understanding this correctly.

Islands start with a positive loan ; within each island, you want to compute a running sum in a subset of rows.

We can identify the islands in a subquery with a window count of positive loans, then do the maths in each group with a conditional expression:

```
select id, created, amount, event, 
    sum(case when (event = 'loan' and amount > 0) or (event = 'spend' and amount < 0) then amount end)
        over(partition by id, grp order by created) as cumulative_sum
from (
    select t.*, 
        sum(case when  event = 'loan' and amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
            over(partition by id order by created) grp
    from tmp t
) t
order by id, created
```

Comment: Thank you for naming the problem! Was very helpful to find more articles on it 

Answer (score 1):

One option would be [something like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/K-5G9kg-):

```
SELECT 
*,
SUM(CASE WHEN cnt >= 1 AND ((scheme != 'loan' AND amount<0) OR (scheme = 'loan' AND amount > 0)) THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created ASC) AS cumulative_sum_spend
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created) cnt
  FROM tmp
) a
```

The idea here is that the inner query's window function counts the number of previous positive values. Then the outer query can do an extra check `cnt >= 1` as part of its window function, so it will only consider values after the first positive one.

Comment: I don't think that would work because the cnt only looks at the row number and if there are more rows (for example adding the following rows: `[(1,'2022-01-08',1000,'loan'),(1, '2022-01-09', -100, 'spend')]` the cumulative sum doesn't start over. But the subquery is a great idea thank you! I'm gonna play around with it to see if I can make it restart each time there's a positive amount in the 'loan' scheme

Comment: If litle change expression in subquery to SUM(CASE WHEN **event='loan' and** amount > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), then   cnt=1  - first row  with event=loan and amount>0  and cnt>=1 -  all next.  'scheme' in query, i think - synonym for event.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the requirements. Can you edit your question for the expected output with those two new rows?

Comment: I've updated the questions sorry if it wasn't articulated well. You're solution is perfect I just needed to add partition by cnt as well.